# django and get_model for a signal?

Tags: django, django-signals

i have a signal -

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_initial_story(sender,instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Story(user = instance, title = 'Random Stories',
            description="Random stories",
            is_closed = False, is_random = True).save()
```

which is cool and all, but i really don't want to have this signal in my models.py

it gets "double imported" somehow, and i would rather that not happen. Yes, i know about the magic trick to stop a signal being run twice, but i just don't trust that. Why have my app do twice the work! Crazy!

Somebody suggested i use `django.db.models.get_model`, but i do not know how to do this! My attempt did not quite work - here is what i tried:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

@receiver(post_save, sendermodel('myapp','User'))
def create_initial_story(sender,instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        get_model('myapp','Story').(user = instance, title = 'Random Stories',
            description="Random stories",
            is_closed = False, is_random = True).save()
```

this yields an exception -

Cannot assign "< Story: Random Stories >": "Story.user" must be a "User" instance.

So! What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
get_model('myapp','Story').(user = instance, title = 'Random Stories',
        description="Random stories",
        is_closed = False, is_random = True).save()
```

`get_model` returns the model class, so you still need `objects.create` to actually create an instance. And, you don't need the `save()` at the end. Try:

```
get_model('myapp','Story').objects.create(user = instance, title = 'Random Stories',
        description="Random stories",
        is_closed = False, is_random = True)
```

Comment: hey, any ideas where the django docs for get_model are? my search on their website and google yielded nada!